# How do i make a clickable button in javascript that adds + 1 to a variable?

Tags: javascript, html

i was wondering how you can make a button that shows up on a html empty canvas, and when you click the button it adds + 1 onto a variable. By the way i am making this javascript code in html, so basically in a text file, then i save it as a html file.
Also please try to keep the code simple. :)

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: i can answer this in a comment, `<button onclick="window.n=window.n+1||1;document.getElementById('x').innerText=window.n">add 1</button><p id="x"></p>`

Answer (score 2):

You can grab the button from the HTML and add a `click` event listener as such. You can do further reading: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp).

```js
let button = document.getElementById("increment");
let count = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
count++;
button.innerText = `The Button has been clicked ${count} times.`
});
```

```html
<button id="increment">The Button has not been clicked yet.</button>
```